# How might I prove or disprove this conjecture: $7p_{k-2} < 8p_{k-4}$ for all $k \ge 35$?

Tags: number-theory

Patterns observed while working with recursive prime factorizations (arXiv:2102.02777) lead me to the following conjecture (which is a specific case of a much more general conjecture that I am not presently prepared to state):

Let $k$ be an integer greater than or equal to 33.  Then $7p_{k} < 8p_{k-2}$, where $p_i$ is the $i$th prime number.

@Lulu and @Peter have been very helpful in pointing me to a solution for that conjecture.  Having experienced so much success, I venture to ask about another special case of the generalized conjecture (please forgive me if I do not immediately see that the answers already given are sufficient to address it):

Let $k$ be an integer greater than or equal to 50.  Then

$p_k < 2p_{k-1} < 3p_{k-1} < 4p_{k-2} < 5p_{k-1} < 6p_{k-2} < 7p_{k-1} < 8p_{k-3} < 9p_{k-2} < 10p_{k-2}$.

Since @lulu was kind enough to subsequently point out that Bertrand's Postulate is sufficient to prove that latter conjecture, I am now ready to present the generalization of the conjecture (note that I begin with $p_{k-1}$ rather than $p_{k}$ to show successive terms in OEIS sequence A073093 as the subtrahend in the subscript):

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}_{+}$.  Then there exists a positive integer $k_{\text{min}}$ such that for all integers $k \ge k_{\text{min}}$,

$p_{k-1} < \cdots < np_{k-a_{n}},$

where $a_{n}$ is the number of prime power divisors of $n$, i.e., $a$ is Sequence A073093 in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences (OEIS).

By the way, I cannot figure out what the pattern is in the sequence of $k_{\text{min}}$ for successive values of $n$; that sequence is $(2,3,8,8,13,13,35,35,10,14,\ldots)$.  Can anyone identify a formula for the sequence?

Comment: Why use $k-2, k-4$ instead of, say, $k, k-2$?  In any case, look at the stronger forms of [Bertrand's Postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate).  Those certainly suffice to prove the claim for large enough $k$ (which can be made explicit).  After that, a simple finite search should suffice (if it is even necessary).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, @lulu!  I used $k-2$,$k-4$ because I foolishly extracted those from my generalized conjecture without rephrasing them as $k$,$k-2$ for $k \ge 33$.  These are patterns I find in the evaluations of stripes of Dyck naturals of semilength k.

Comment: @lulu I guess the limit $10^8$ (the larger prime is the smallest prime exceeding $10^8$) is enough. Upto this, the conjecture holds.

Comment: @Peter  Oh, more than enough.  Much more.  I just did a quick calculation and I think that Dusart's easiest estimate, $p_{n+1}<\left(1+\frac 1{2\ln^2p_n}\right)p_{n}$ suffices, and that holds for $n≥463$.

Comment: Hi @lulu... your answer was so helpful that I amended the text of the question to propose a more extensive special case of my generalized conjecture.  Forgive my stupidity if your existing replies are already sufficient to address the new conjecture; I'm not much of a math person.

Comment: The same argument ought to work. Just to put it into perspective, The Dusart estimate I mentioned is *much* stronger than you are after.  We have $\left(1+\frac 1{2\ln^2p_{465}}\right)\approx 1.00761$ (see [WA1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2B1%2F%282*ln%5E2%28prime%5B465%5D%29%29%29)) which is a lot tighter than you need.  Of course, you still have to search up to $k=465$ or so, but Wolfram Alpha can handle that range easily, as in [WA2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Max%5BTable%5BN%5Bprime%5Bn%5D%2Fprime%5Bn-2%5D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C50%2C1000%7D%5D%5D)

Comment: @lulu, thanks again.  I have added the generalized conjecture to the question text, and this conjecture brings up another sequence which I have not been able to make any progress on: $(2,3,8,8,13,13,35,35,10,14,\cdots)$.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Nope.  [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C3%2C8%2C8%2C13%2C13%2C35%2C35&sort=&language=english&go=Search) doesn't recognize it, just to say.

Comment: Added a proof that such a $k_{min}$ exists, but finding a bound on it seems quite annoying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: As has been pointed out in the comments, there is an error in this proof (basically from copying the bounds incorrectly from wikipedia) which means the details of the argument are wrong. However, the overall gist of the argument is correct so I think it is worth it to leave this answer up. Just note that the bounds should be

$$k\ln(k)+k\ln(\ln(k))-k<p_k<k\ln(k)+k\ln(\ln(k))$$

where I had accidentally copied

$$k\ln(k)+k\ln(\ln(k))-1<p_k<k\ln(k)+k\ln(\ln(k))$$

With this fix, the $K$ described below should be $611$ instead of the $27$ that I originally got.

---

As has been mentioned in the comments, this conjecture seems true but case checking might be unavoidable. To prove its true for **some** $k\in\mathbb{N}$, I use the following [bounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number)

$$k\ln(k)+k\ln(\ln(k))-1<p_k<k\ln(k)+k\ln(\ln(k))$$

for $k\geq 6$. Then

$$\frac{7p_k}{8p_{k-2}}<\frac{7}{8}\cdot \frac{k\ln(k)+k\ln(\ln(k))}{(k-2)\ln(k-2)+(k-2)\ln(\ln(k-2))-1}$$

We must now find some $K\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $k\geq K$ implies

$$\frac{7}{8}\cdot \frac{k\ln(k)+k\ln(\ln(k))}{(k-2)\ln(k-2)+(k-2)\ln(\ln(k-2))-1}<1$$

Of course, such a $K$ must exist since

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{7}{8}\cdot \frac{k\ln(k)+k\ln(\ln(k))}{(k-2)\ln(k-2)+(k-2)\ln(\ln(k-2))-1}=\frac{7}{8}$$

the only difficulty being finding such a $K$. Okay, here is a method for finding such a $K$. Define

$$f(x)= \frac{x\ln(x)+x\ln(\ln(x))}{(x-2)\ln(x-2)+(x-2)\ln(\ln(x-2))-1}$$

Then differentiating gives two awful functions in the numerator and denominator

$$f'(x)=\frac{g(x)}{h(x)^2}$$

(I haven't written them here since they are rather large and unweildy and don't really provide any insight into the problem). Since $h(x)^2>0$, it is sufficient to find $X$ such that $x\geq X$ implies $g(x)<0$. Again, after lots of simplification, we find that

$$g(x)<-2\ln(\ln(x))^2$$

(with the minor stipulation that $x\geq 3^3$ in order for some of the inequalities we used to work). That is, the derivative of $f(x)$ is always negative for $x\geq 3^3$. This basically completes the proof since

$$\frac{7}{8}f(27)=0.975<1$$

Thus, a sufficient bound is $K=27$ which is already less than what you need. This checks well with the actual bound, since the final prime the conjecture is not true for is $k=25$. That is

$$\frac{7p_{25}}{8p_{23}}=\frac{679}{664}>1$$

and the actual bound is $K=26$.

---

FINAL EDIT: This edit will prove the existance of $K(n)$ such that

$$p_k<2p_{k-1}<3p_{k-2}<...<np_{k-a_n}$$

where $a_n$ is the number of non-distinct prime factors in $n$, is true for all $k\geq K(n)$

By the prime number theorem, we have that

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{ap_{k}}{bp_{k-r}}=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{ak\ln(k)}{b(k-r)\ln(k-r)}=\frac{a}{b}$$

(note that $r\in\mathbb{Z}$). Thus, $K(2)$ exists since

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{p_k}{2p_{k-1}}=\frac{1}{2}$$

(in fact, $K(2)=2$ follows from Bertrand's postulate). Now, to find $K(n+1)$ from $K(n)$, define $K(n+1)$ as the maximum of $K(n)$ and $K^{'}$. Here, $K^{'}$ is defined as the smallest natural such that $k\geq K^{'}$ implies

$$\frac{np_{k-a_n}}{(n+1)p_{k-{a_{n+1}}}}<1$$

Again, we know such a $K^{'}$ must exist from the prime number theorem. In this manner, all $K(n)$ can be defined. Of course, finding these $K(n)$ and proving that they are certain values is a much more difficult challenge.

Comment: This is extremely valuable to me, @QC_QAOA.  I will ruminate on your answer, and consider how it might figure into my next revision of arXiv:2102.02777.  Here's a question regarding citations: In a math paper, the author should only cite sources providing results that are not generally known; does your answer come under that heading?  For example, I would not cite a reference as offering a definition of prime factorization.  Is your reply sufficiently novel that I should cite it in my work?

Comment: about your very first equation: isn't it rather $k\ln(k)+k\ln(\ln(k))-\pmb{k}<p_k< \dots$?

Comment: @JustAsking No, cite the original bounds author since that is the actual important work (which can be found by following the wikipedia trail). Also, as the commenter above me pointed out, I made an error in my calculations. The overall method would be the same, but you should go through the details yourself to make doubly sure everything is correct